# How to convert MH File Field's with multiple images?

Tags: matrix, migration

Anyone successfully convert MH file fieldtype that has multiple images to a matrix or similar? I have some entries that have multiple images tied to a single MH file field. I'm in the process of upgrading EE1 to EE2, and fields with just one image are fine, but entries with multiple images have data stored like:

```
image_1.jpg
image_2.jpg
```

I've seen these threads for after upgrading to EE2 for [nGen file field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041491/expressionengine-1-to-expressionengine-2-upgrade-with-ngen-file-field) and [MH file field](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/218268/), but these are specific to single files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All credit goes to Brandon. I searched and found this [**thread**](https://getsatisfaction.com/pixelandtonic/topics/upgrading_file_field_into_ee2) last night which was ultimately the solution. I'll post the script below as that thread was a little confusing to follow until they got it working.

You'll need to convert all MH File fields to a Matrix field first. Then run the script below.

> Make sure to replace XX with your Matrix field ID, YY with your File
>   column ID, and ZZ with your file upload directory ID.

```
<?php

    // Converts Mark Huot's File Field with multiple images to a Matrix column
    mysql_connect("localhost", "db_username", "db_password") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("database_name") or die(mysql_error());

    $query = mysql_query('SELECT site_id, entry_id, field_id_XX FROM exp_channel_data WHERE field_id_XX IS NOT NULL');
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

        // get the file names
        $files = array_filter(preg_split('/[\r\n]/', $row['field_id_XX']));

        // add them to exp_matrix_data
        foreach ($files as $i => $file) {

            mysql_query('INSERT INTO exp_matrix_data (site_id, entry_id, field_id, row_order, col_id_YY)
            VALUES ('.$row['site_id'].', '.$row['entry_id'].', XX, '.$i.', "{filedir_ZZ}'.$file.'")');
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!!!

Comment: That's awesome!